# How can i create a secured and an unsecured version of a method-security protected DAO

Tags: java, spring-security, authorization

In my current project we have a set of service classes that are secured by method-based security.

now in some cases the "system" needs to call secured methods on its own. (for example: a user leaves a channel and the channel is implicitly closed because its empty. normaly 'close' is protected).

How do i provide access to a service class in a secured and an unsecured way at the same time?

**EDIT - short example**

during auhentication the system checks if here is an active ban against the user.

```
public User authenticate(String name, String token) throws BadCredentialsException, RuntimeException {
    User user = get(name);
    if (user == null || !user.getToken().equals(token)) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Project/Username/Password");
    }
    Ban userBan = banService.getBanForUser(user);
    if (userBan != null) {
        throw new UserBannedException("User was baned", userBan);
    }
    return user
}
```

BUT access to any bans is protected by method-based security so not every user can "get" them.

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public Ban getBanForUser(User user) {
    return ...
}
```

so basicly i need two ways to access this method. one that is protected by the spring-security inteceptor (for "users") and one that is not (for the "system").

is this possible without wrapper classes, inheritance magic, ...

it would be great if i could define two spring beans that have the same class one with spring-security and one whithout.

Comment: You can protect methods based on role basis, if ROLE_SUPER then give access to `close()` method, or if other roles then protect, Also give more details so that we can help you.

Comment: @Nandkumar i added a short example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution (nothing close to something elegant, of course) would be simulate the authentication of a super user right before you call the protected methods. Something like this:

```java
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(privileged user here);    
Ban userBan = banService.getBanForUser(user);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
```

Comment: currently i do something like that, but i preserve the original context so i can restore it after the call.